# git ignore sync issue

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I had a file, actually a config file, in my `origin/master` and in my `origin/feature/xy branch`, which I removed. I deleted the file locally and commited deleted changes to remote. When I look inside the bitbucket the file is gone in `origin/master`.

Now I wish the file to be present again therefore I tried to create the file again and to push it to `origin/master` at the same time hoever I added the file name to .gitignore

The idea of all this is to have the config file in `origin/master` so build server may use the settings inside but also to prevent the `origin/feature/xy` branches to overwrite the file on `origin/master`. The file shall be present on `origin/master` and ignored in each new branch created. Those branches may have own settings inside file but they may never push their local changes to `origin/master`

How do I achive this? The file is gone now..

Comment: Git either tracks a file or it doesn't. If you, in a different branch, modify a tracked file and commit, then merge this branch into master, master will get those changes (or a merge conflict, depending on the scenario). If, on the other hand, you remove the file from master, then create that new branch, that branch won't have the file. If you now add the file back to master, you can keep it on master without your extra branch modifying it, or deleting it. However, if you now merge master up into your other branch, the file is back.

Comment: In what scenario do I get the desired behavior I described in my question?

Answer (score 0):

The "ignore rules" (e.g. .gitignore) functionality won't do what you want; they only do one thing: tell git that if an untracked file matches a pattern, git should pretend it isn't there.

It doesn't prevent merges of a path, or prevent branches from seeing the file at a path, or anything like that.  If a file is in the repo, even if its path is matched by ignore rules, the ignore rules do nothing at all with respect to that file.

But how to do what you want?

Well, the most complete solution would be to find a home for your config file outside of source control.  You could keep your file on the build server (and possibly a second location if the build server isn't backed up) and remove it from all branches including master, then add it to .gitignore so that nobody accidentally commits a stray copy.

The only down-side to that is, if the config file has to evolve such that a particular version of the config file is needed for a given version of your source code, you lose tracking of that relationship and have to use some other mechanism to keep track of that.  But then again, if the main way this file changes is evolution with your source code, then keeping it off the feature branches may not be the best thing in the first place.

Another (partial) solution would be to use git hooks to reject any merge to master that changes the file.  Again, this only prevents accidents (as you'd still presumably need a way to modify the file on master over time).  It doesn't keep the file from being seen on the branches.